# How to change the easing functions of a drawer in material-ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How do i change the the used easing functions a drawer uses?

I need to change both ease function to the same value. Using MuiThemeProvider didnt seem to work. The Drawer component also doesnt take any transition argument but tranistion duration.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score -1):

`Drawer` receives a `TransitionComponent`. As you can see [here](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/d23785f757ead3e091f7eef97fe58d99cad71407/packages/material-ui/src/Drawer/Drawer.js#L119) the default value is `Slider` component. So you can make your own custom transition component with your custom easing (You can use `Slider` as well and customize it) and pass it to your drawer.